# What is meaning of LAV2P basis set?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, energy, density-functional-theory, basis-set

I am working on energy optimization of molecular structure using DFT with **Schrödinger software** and I found that job is running on LAV2P basis set. I want to know what is the meaning of this basis set in particular and how it is different from other basis sets.

Also, I want to compare which basis set corresponds to this in Gaussian software.

P.S. The only info that I found on my research on the internet is the full form of LAV2P.

Comment: If I'm right, the more common name for this basis is LANL2DZ (for Los Alamos National Lab double zeta). You can find out more about it at and the way it is entered in different programs at https://www.basissetexchange.org/

Comment: Indeed, as shown in http://glab.cchem.berkeley.edu/glab/schrodinger.old/jaguar_command_reference/jaguar_files_basis_ecp.htm It looks like the definition of the basis set is the same of LANL2DZ https://www.basissetexchange.org/basis/lanl2dz/format/gaussian94/?version=0&elements=11